# finish activity from alarm manager onreceive method

Tags: android, alarm

I my app I am using alarm manager like this in mainactivity.

```
Date dat  = new Date();//initializes to now
        Calendar cal_alarm = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar cal_now = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal_now.setTime(dat);
        cal_alarm.setTime(dat);

        cal_alarm.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 6);
        cal_alarm.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 51);
        cal_alarm.set(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
       cal_alarm.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
       if(cal_alarm.before(cal_now)){//if its in the past increment
            cal_alarm.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
        }
       Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
       //intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE_1, id1);
       PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(),1, intent, 0);
       AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
       alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal_alarm.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

AlarmReceiver.java

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    UserFunctions userFunctions;
    AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> mRegisterTask1;
    HashMap<String,String> x2;
     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {

         Toast.makeText(arg0, "Alarm received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            DatabaseHandler1 db = new DatabaseHandler1(arg0 );

            int count = db.getRowCount();
            if(count > 0){
                x2 =db.getUserDetails();
                String Uid =  x2.get("uid");
            db.resetTables();
            mRegisterTask1 = new AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>() {
                UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
                    Log.d("Button", "Logout");
                    String value = params[0];
                    JSONObject json1 = userFunction.logoutUser1(value);
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                    mRegisterTask1 = null;
                }

            };
            mRegisterTask1.execute(Uid, null, null)
            }
     }
     }
```

what I need is I also want to finish the application or atleast main activity when the alarm receives . How can I do that,Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can call [finish()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29) where you want to stop the Activity.